# How to set and get LINUX ENV variables in Jenkins pipelines?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

This might be a stupid question, but I'm unable to solve it. I would like to set and get LINUX (not Jenkins) ENV variables. I'm aware how to deal with Jenkins environment variables (e.g. `env.JENKINS_HOME`) but Linux ENV variables seem to be closed off.

When using `sh "printenv"` then this prints all Linux ENV variables as expected, but setting them via `export SOME_VAR=123` doesn't seem to work. `printenv` isn't showing it. Using `System.getenv("SOME_VAR")` also doesn't work.

For example:

```
stage('echo stuff') {
    steps {
        script {
            sh "printenv"
            sh "export SOME_VAR=123"
            sh 'echo $SOME_VAR'
        }
    }
}
```

Produces this:

```
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (echo stuff)
[Pipeline] script
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] sh
+ export SOME_VAR=123
+ SOME_VAR=123
[Pipeline] sh
+ echo

[Pipeline] }
```

I wasn't able to find help on this presumably very common problem, because everything available deals with Jenkins environment variables.

Comment: I might be stupid. `sh "printenv"` does not print the Linux ENV vars, but the Jenkins environment variables.

Comment: I am unsure what a "linux env variable" is, but modifying the `env` object will set environment variables globally within the Jenkins Pipeline, reading the `env` object views JP env variables, and executing the `env` shell command would display the total environment variables for the shell process. These would comprise all environment variables you would be concerned with writing and reading.

Comment: Linux ENV variables are like global variables for the shell, see [here](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-set-and-list-environment-variables-on-linux). Some CLI tools needs them to work, e.g. for authentication. Jenkins seems to do some black magic and sets its own environment variables, which are also magically available to CLI tools. So my mistake was to assume that Linux ENV vars would be accessible in Jenkins and that Jenkins ENV variables are not accessible to CLI tools. Has probably to  do with the fact that Jenkins can be used on Windows as well. Not sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is, that every `sh`-block is its own shell session. So if you export a variable with `sh "export SOME_VAR=123"` it is not set in the next line. You want to use shell multi-line like this:

```
stage('echo stuff') {
  steps {
    script {
        sh '''
          export SOME_VAR=123
          echo $SOME_VAR
        '''
    }
  }
}
```

This will work as you expect.

More info can be found [Jenkins.io running-multiple-steps](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/tour/running-multiple-steps/)